# axios request return empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./App.css";
import Games from "./Components/games";
import Header from "./Components/header";
import Sidebar from "./Components/sidebar";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [gamesData, setGamesData] = useState([]);

  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/games",
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-key": "920bb46b09msh9ae1555975a837bp1a6946jsn760df3d3a8e4",
      "x-rapidapi-host": "rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
     axios
      .request(options)
      .then((response) => {
         setGamesData(response.data.results)
        console.log(gamesData);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("error");
      });
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="h-screen flex flex-col bg-gradient-to-r from-gray-700 via-gray-900 to-black">
      <Header />
      <div className="flex h-full ">
        <Sidebar />
        <Games />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Hey guys have a goody day.I try to get data from api.But i try to do this metod i get empty array.If i remove second parameter of useEffect function which is `[]` it workd and returns data every single second.What i should do to get data for once ?

Comment: State changes are asynchronous, you can't `console.log` state on the next line and see the change. Print your state in the main body of the function to see it's latest value

Comment: Thank you so much sir it works fine. @Jayce444

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need `console.log` the `gamesData` in the App component.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./App.css";
import Games from "./Components/games";
import Header from "./Components/header";
import Sidebar from "./Components/sidebar";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [gamesData, setGamesData] = useState([]);

  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com/games",
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-key": "920bb46b09msh9ae1555975a837bp1a6946jsn760df3d3a8e4",
      "x-rapidapi-host": "rawg-video-games-database.p.rapidapi.com",
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
     axios
      .request(options)
      .then((response) => {
         setGamesData(response.data.results)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("error");
      });
  },[]);

  console.log(gamesData);

  return (
    <div className="h-screen flex flex-col bg-gradient-to-r from-gray-700 via-gray-900 to-black">
      <Header />
      <div className="flex h-full ">
        <Sidebar />
        <Games />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

P.S. You have exposed your API key in the code snippet that you posted above. It's a sensitive credential. I recommend you delete this key now and generate a new key from RapidAPI Developer Dashboard.